# Pyodbc - How can i query a database using Variables Python

Tags: python, database, pyodbc

I'm trying to query my database in order to show all the customers with the provided first name, which is stored in a variable. However I can't figure out how to include the variable into the query.

Does anyone knows a way to do this using variables?

Comment: Do you want your query to look for rows with a specific `firstname` like 'Gord', or do you want it to look for rows that have have *any* `firstname` entered (i.e., `firstname` IS NOT NULL)?

Comment: Have you attempted to code this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from the docs here:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started

ODBC supports parameters using a question mark as a place holder in the SQL. You provide the values for the question marks by passing them after the SQL:

```
cursor.execute("""
    select user_id, user_name
      from users
     where last_logon < ?
       and bill_overdue = ?
""", datetime.date(2001, 1, 1), 'y')
```

So in your case it might be `where user_name = ?`